# Continuous refreshing of pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

When I load a page such as

```
https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/<number>/<username>?tab=reputation
```

the browser keeps refreshing it, making it impossible to open up a closed day, for instance. Moreover, on my rep page, the recent upvotes are immediately classified with the old ones and the same happens with the responses tab.

The browser I use is Safari 5.0.3 on Mac OS X (10.6). The behavior started some days ago (not more than a couple of weeks, IIRC).

EDIT

The problems seems to be still present; for example when I try this page

https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg?tab=activity&sort=revisions

the continuous refreshing problem appears.

EDIT2

I get the undesired behavior when I access the following page:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg?tab=answers

and then click on the "[2]" square to go to the second page: the page that appears refreshes continuously. However, if I go directly to, say,

https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg?tab=answers&sort=newest&page=3

then the problem doesn't appear immediately, but only when going to another page by clicking on the squares below.

Comment: Can you check that you don't have the browser setup to refresh the page? (I know you can do this with the context menu in FF.) At least in FF10 on Win7, I'm not seeing that behavior.

Comment: There's no such option is Safari, that I know of. It happens only on some kind of pages in the StackExchange network.

Comment: Does it happen if you use another browser on the same OS? For instance, Chrome?

Comment: It doesn't happen with Firefox 3.0.8

Comment: Part of this at least is [this issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122044/highlighting-of-new-rep-broken-again), but Safari 5.0.x refreshing constantly may be a separate bug in History.js.

Comment: Sounds similar to/closely related to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122230/profile-view-tabs-will-not-scroll-more-than-halfway/122511 (and its dupe http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122375/community-user-reputation-tab-acts-up). Something changed a week and a half ago that doesn't play nice with WebKit.

Comment: @TimStone Thanks for the pointer. It seems just the same problem.

Comment: @egreg - I can't repro this after the fix on the related issue, can you see if this is fixed on your end?

Comment: @NickCraver It seems to be fixed! Now the page doesn't spawn a refresh after being loaded. Thanks

Comment: @egreg - good to hear, leaving a note and completing this :)

Answer (score 7):

There was a bug introduced by a change on the Webkit side, it's now accounted for in our JavaScript and should behave properly.

Comment: I've edited the question pointing to a page where the problem is again appearing

Comment: It's not happening to me with Firefox.

Comment: @JohnSaunders It's a specific problems of browsers relying on MacOS X WebKit such as Safari.

Comment: As I've already remarked some days ago in an edit to my answer, the problem has reappeared.

Comment: @egreg - I can't repro this on any browser I try, I'll need to get someone with a Mac at the office to try Safari to repro, will get back to you on this.

Comment: @NickCraver I've added some info about how to reproduce the problem (or at least how I get stuck into it).

Comment: @NickCraver Now that the issue seems fixed, would it be a good idea to have the problem and solution as a wiki post? Would be helpful to others and an interesting read. Or is it posted anywhere already?

Comment: @NickCraver The problem persists. I tried just now.

Comment: @egreg I can't repro this on Safari on a Mac, but I'm on OS X 10.7.3

Comment: @Jin Just tried again

Comment: @egreg - We simply cannot repro this, we've tested in your exact browser and OS.  There has to be something else in play, a browser extension, user script, etc.